# Receiving NPM err: Unexpected string in JSON at position 20938 within an ionic 3 project

Tags: json, node.js, ionic3

Not sure where the error is. (* is where private project information is held, i.e. Facebook app id and the app name) I have been receiving this error for a while now and I can't figure it out, is there something I'm missing?

```
{
    "name": "****",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "author": "Ionic Framework",
    "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
        "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
        "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "4.4.3",
        "@angular/compiler": "4.4.3",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.4.3",
        "@angular/core": "4.4.3",
        "@angular/forms": "4.4.3",
        "@angular/http": "4.4.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "4.4.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.4.3",
        "@firebase/webchannel-wrapper": "^0.2.1",
        "@ionic-native/camera": "^4.3.0",
        "@ionic-native/core": "^4.3.1",
        "@ionic-native/facebook": "^4.2.1",
        "@ionic-native/image-picker": "^4.3.1",
        "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.3.1",
        "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.3.1",
        "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
        "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.2",
        "cordova-browser": "^4.1.0",
        "cordova-ios": "^4.4.0",
        "cordova-plugin-camera": "^2.4.1",
        "cordova-plugin-compat": "^1.2.0",
        "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.4",
        "cordova-plugin-facebook4": "^1.9.1",
        "cordova-plugin-firebase": "^0.1.24",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.0.3",
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.2.2",
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.1",
        "firebase": "^4.5.0",
        "ionic-angular": "3.7.1",
        "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
        "ionic-tags-input": "0.0.6",
        "ionicons": "3.0.0",
        "ng-tags-input": "^3.2.0",
        "promise-polyfill": "^6.0.2",
        "rxjs": "5.4.3",
        "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
        "zone.js": "0.8.18"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular/cli": "^1.4.3",
        "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.0.0",
        "typescript": "2.5.3"
    },
    "description": "An Ionic project",
    "cordova": {
        "plugins": {
            "cordova-plugin-facebook4": {
                "APP_ID": "***********",
                "APP_NAME": "****"
            },
            "cordova-plugin-device": {},
            "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
            "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
            "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
            "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
            "cordova-plugin-firebase": {},
            "cordova-plugin-camera": {}
        },
        "platforms": [
            "browser",
            "ios"
        ]
    }
}
```

Or could this be an error with my node or NPM? It would be nice to have some fresh eyes to have a look

Comment: Did you try deleting `node_modules` folder?

Comment: yeah, it doesn't let me run the 'npm install' method to even install my node modules

Comment: i figured it out. i hade to run the command 'rm package-lock.json' and then everything worked :)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Run the command 'rm package-lock.json', then re-ran 'npm install' and everything worked :)

Comment: In case it helps someone else, 
I had to run `rm package-lock.json` 
then run `npm install --package-lock` 
before `npm i` would work.